# how to install mysqlclient lib as required by diesel

Tags: apt, software-installation, mysql, rust

Compiling [diesel_cli](https://crates.io/crates/diesel_cli) on Ubuntu 16.04, I'm unable to find which package I should install to get rid if the message

```
~$ cargo install diesel_cli
    Updating crates.io index
  Installing diesel_cli v1.4.0
...
   Compiling toml v0.4.10
   Compiling diesel_cli v1.4.0
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" "-Wl,--as-needed"
....
note: ld: library not found for -lmysqlclient
```

There was also another dependency, on libpq, but that was solved installing postgresql. Of course I have installed more or less all what I've found related to mysql, indeed the [mysql crate](https://docs.rs/mysql/17.0.0/mysql/) installs and execute without problems.

My last attempt have been

```
sudo apt-get install mysql\*
```

but the problem is not solved.
Any hint ?

Comment: Likely [libmysqlclient-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libmysqlclient-dev)

Comment: Thanks so much, @steeldriver. Indeed now I have a diesel running :)

Comment: If you would like to convert the comment to an answer, I would thank you. It was a real nuisance and stop in my rust apprenticeship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message noted *"library not found for -lmysqlclient"*
As you probably observed, installing mysql doesn't solve. To resolve it, install libmysqlclient-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

For others encountering a similar issue executing *"cargo install diesel_cli"*, you may also want to add:

```
sudo apt install libpq-dev 
sudo apt install libmariadbclient-dev-compat
sudo apt install libsqlite3-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `Nditah` for

```
sudo apt install libpq-dev
```

Was getting this error:
`= note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpq`

Works for postgres now.

Running `cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features postgres` with no issues now.

Comment: It is not clear what does or does not work from your answer. Could you clarify?